# TD In Table If/Else

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have got a in a table. I would like an if/else statement that adds 92 to variable x if the td is in a table.

This is the code I have got but obviously the if/else isn't what I want.

```
//Html
<table id="Tableleft">
   <tr>
     <td id="92">Text 1</td>
   </tr>
</table>

//Javascript
var x = 0
if ( document.getElementByID('92')) { 
//Help Here Please
}
```

Comment: You haven't closed your `if` condition's parenthesis

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is required that all `<td>` elements live inside a `<table>`, in order for the markup to be valid.

Comment: @bgoldst OP could be attempting to write a _HTML validator_

Answer (score 1):

Iterate up the *DOM Tree* using [`elem.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) to see if an ancestor is a `<table>`.

I'm being very lenient in the definition of your requirement of *"if the TD is in a table"*, you may want to be more strict (e.g. only permitting `<tr>`, `<tbody>`, `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` and `<table>` as valid ancestors for your `+92` action to work).

```
var x = 0,
    td = document.getElementByID('92'),
    e; // we'll use this in our loop
if (td) { // `td` is not `null` -> we found a node with _id_ `92`
    e = td;
    while (e = e.parentNode) { // iterate up the DOM tree
        if (e.tagName === 'TABLE') { // the `td` node has an ancestor `<table>`
            x += 92;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Using a plain number as an *id attribute* may have unexpected results. For best results have the first character as `a-zA-Z` and avoid characters with special meanings in selectors `.#:@`